# How to break xlib's next_event()?

Tags: python, pyside, xlib, qthread

I am using `QThread` (pyside) for handling global hot-keys on X11. I have some simple while loop which looks like:

```
while self.doRun:                
      event=root.display.next_event()
      if event.type==X.KeyPress:
      ....
```

But `next_event()` is known for waiting for actual event. So how do I stop that loop without waiting for another keystroke? I was thinking about sending fake event with keypress via Xlib but I don't think that's a right way. Also `.terminate()` on that event is not an option... with pyside it crashes whole app with:

> Fatal Python error: This thread state must be current when releasing

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

It's a late answer, but I had the same issue, so maybe it's still helpful for someone.

Based on the [documentation](http://python-xlib.sourceforge.net/doc/html/python-xlib_11.html#SEC10), you can use Python's [select module](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/select.html) to receive events with a time-out.

A solution using select basically consists of two steps: 1) work off all pending events, and 2) wait with a *select* call until new I/O-events arrive. If no events arrive, the method will timeout after a certain time.

Such an event loop could look like this:

```py
# Main loop, handling events
def loop(self):
  self.loop_cond = True
  timeout=5 # timeout in seconds

  while self.loop_cond:
    # handle all available events
    i = self.d.pending_events()
    while i > 0:
      event = self.display.next_event()
      self.handle_event(event)
      i = i - 1

    # Wait for display to send something, or a timeout of one second
    readable, w, e = select.select([self.display], [], [], timeout)

    # if no files are ready to be read, it's an timeout
    if not readable:
      self.handle_timeout()
```

I've created a gist with a [small example](https://gist.github.com/stefanthaler/7f5541d45240e567cea6abcdc50c815e).

Answer (score 0):

You can send a close event (in X11 [a destroy event](http://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/window-state-change/destroy.html) perhaps?), to be more explicit. Another idea is to check if there are any events pending first:

```
if root.display.pending_events():
    event = root.display.next_event()
    # process event
```

However this constitutes [busy-waiting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting), so I'd go for the first option.

Comment: I was trying that `pending_events` already but as I expected it's terrible for app performance. Adding sleep (which is stupid itself) makes it even worse. Do you have some example how to send that close event? Do I need to register it somehow? I haven't found much info about that...

Comment: @middleofdreams Yeah, documentation on Qt's bindings is quite sparse. I'm guessing that you should be able to send this event in the same manner as a simulated keypress event, just with the [appropriate event type](http://pyside.github.io/docs/pyside/PySide/QtCore/QEvent.html#PySide.QtCore.PySide.QtCore.QEvent.Type). Also you might want to checkout native Qt's documentation - it contains more information, and most of it applies also to Qt's bindings.

Comment: OK I was thinking you're talking about Xlib events... Actually QThread's close event doesn't work like I wanted to.

Comment: @middleofdreams No, sorry, I got these two confused. Qt's close event won't affect `QThread` of course. In this case you would need something like that in X11 - maybe a destroy event (I've added a link in the answer)?